# Handle multiple input checkboxes in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have data like this:

```
const [purchaseTypes, setPurchaseTypes] = useState([]);

const purchaseInitData = [
    { id: 1, name: 'liveType', purchaseType: 'liveType', label: 'purchase live training' },
    { id: 2, name: 'courseType', purchaseType: 'courseType', label: 'purchase course videos'}];
```

input checkboxes:

```
{purchaseData.map((item, index) => {
    return (
        <div className="flex items-center mb-2" key={index}>
            <input type="checkbox" id={item.id} name={item.name} onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e, index)} />
            <label htmlFor={`custom-checkbox-${index}`} style={{ marginLeft: '15px' }}>{item.label}</label>
        </div>
    )
})}

const handleOnChange = (e, i) => {
    const newData = [...purchaseData];
    const { checked } = e.target;
    if (checked) {
        setPurchaseTypes((prev) => [...prev, newData[i]]);
    } else {
        setPurchaseTypes(newData.splice(i, 1));
    }
}
```

I am able to set data to state but unable to remove the last one when I uncheck

Comment: Maybe the problem relies in `splice` since it is an in-place method. Try calling it outside the `setPurchaseTypes` and then, add `newData` in `setPurchaseTypes`

Comment: @LejdiPrifti Still the same

Comment: Does it get removed from `newData` or it remains unchanged ?

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet you have provided is not very clear. Do you also have purchaseTypes state in your code? And what are you trying to display, purchaseData? But. it is not initialised or set in the code. It would be helpful if you could post your whole code.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please add these requirements in a comment.

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by using filter:

```
const handleOnChange = (e, i) => {
    const { checked, id } = e.target;
    if (checked) {
        setPurchaseTypes([...purchaseTypes, purchaseData[i]]);
    } else {
        setPurchaseTypes((prev) => prev.filter((item) => {
            return item.id !== parseInt(id)
        }))
    }
}
```

Comment: Using filter is the correct way when you want to remove an element from an array. The problem in your first attempt was that you were using same index number in two different arrays (purchaseData, purchaseTypes).